# Remove all properties in mp3 files with non-ASCII characters

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, mp3, metadata

How to remove all properties in mp3 files with non-ASCII characters in the file name (Chinese character)? I tried ID3 kill but it said something like Error #123 Could not open *file path*.
In the *file path*, I saw my Chinese character become `?` (eg. C:\Users\Hello???????.mp3)

*Notes: I am going to delete all Contributing Artist in the property (in batch, I know how to do it one by one, but I have thousands of files) because it contains random characters that is very ugly and unneat.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

- Select all the files in Explorer; you may use
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
- Right-click any one of the files and select Properties
- Go to the Details tab
- Click "Remove Properties and Personal Information"
- Click "Remove the following properties from this file:"
- Click "Select All"
- Click OK.

Comment: I tried your solution before, but it doesn't work as there were a few of aac file. I move the aac files out of the folder and perform the solution above and it works. Thanks.